# Blender 2.91 Drop Menus and Tooltips transparency and partial view problem

Tags: customization

[image: drop menu transparency]

After installing Blender 2.91 version on my old (late 2009 iMac) all drop menus and tooltips  are visible to me, only partially and transparent. How can I change it?

Comment: Most likely an issue with an unsupported GPU or the Drivers for the GPU not being up to date or broken. Update or Downgrade the drivers.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes that make sense. I have installed version 2.8 and now all work perfectly. My old iMac GPU does not meet requirements for 2.9 version.